# How to move cursor to Vue methods, computeds, data quickly in VS Code?

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, vetur

I already tried using the symbol explorer in VSCode (CTRL+P then write @). It allows me to jump to data (because it's a method) but it won't jump to normal properties like "computed:" or "methods:"?

This would be useful when eg. I look at my component and think "Aha! I need to add a computed, so let's jump to computeds". I could just CTRL+F but this sometimes doesn't work if another variable or comment has 'computed' in its name

Answer (score 4):

Currently, you can

1. use `Ctrl+R` to open `Go To Symbol in Editor`,
2. then enter some words like `data`, `computed` or `methods` and etc.,
3. then press `Enter`

The cursor would be moved to the selected symbol. Tested in Win10/v1.48.2

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way how to do that is probably using [Bookmarks extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alefragnani.Bookmarks&WT.mc_id=vscodecandothat-dotcom-team).

I am using them and also I haven't find a better way how to solve same problem as you have.